# Lag query pulling in incorrect data

Tags: sql, oracle, case, partitioning, lag

I have the below table (labelled Original Table) with the following columns:
BU_Code (store code), contact_key (cutomer ID), Bu_key (store number), TXN_Mth (month of trasaction in 2021), Fragrance/Cosmetics/Personal flag (flag for type of product bought).

[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGQ1T.jpg)

I am trying to create a new table based on this which lists the previous month the customer shopped in (Pre_txn_mth) and using a CASE state to determine if they are a new customer (no previous transction before 2021), returning (shopped within 12 months) or reactivated (last shop more than 12 months ago).

However when I create the table it is listing future transactions as the previous tranaction. Below is an image from the new table in which Contact_key 1196 is pulled correctly but 1443 is not. [Error in Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bElvo.jpg)

This is the code I have tried different variations of but same error:

```
CREATE TABLE TPS_TABLE_B AS 
    (
    SELECT 
      B.* 
    , LAG(TXN_MTH) OVER (ORDER BY CONTACT_KEY, TXN_MTH) PRE_TXN_MTH
    --, TXN_MTH - 100
    , CASE 
        WHEN LAG(TXN_MTH) OVER (ORDER BY CONTACT_KEY, TXN_MTH) IS NULL THEN 'NEW'
        WHEN TXN_MTH - 100 <  (LAG(TXN_MTH) OVER (ORDER BY CONTACT_KEY, TXN_MTH)) THEN 'RETURNING'
        WHEN TXN_MTH - 100 >= (LAG(TXN_MTH) OVER (ORDER BY CONTACT_KEY, TXN_MTH)) THEN 'REATIVATED'--REACTIVATED IS NO TRANSACTION IN PAST 12 MONTHS
        ELSE 'OTHER'
      END AS CUST_TYPE     
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT 
            CONTACT_KEY
        ,   BU_CODE
        ,   BU_KEY
        ,   TXN_MTH
        ,   FRAGRANCE_FLAG   
        ,   COSMETICS_FLAG  
        ,   PERSONALCARE_FLAG     
    
        FROM TPS_TABLE_A    
        ) B
    )
;
```

Comment: You need a Partition By in your Lag function. Try:   
```
LAG(TXN_MTH) OVER (Partition By Contact Key ORDER BY CONTACT_KEY, TXN_MTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CTE (or use this code as subquery) to get some derived values that you will use in main query to get everything you need.

```sql
WITH
    c_months AS
        (
            Select
                BU_CODE, BU_KEY, CONTACT_KEY, 
                TXN_MTH, FRAGRANCE_FLAG, COSMETICS_FLAG, PERSONALCARE_FLAG, 
                CASE WHEN SubStr(TXN_MTH - 1, -2) = '00' THEN  TXN_MTH - 1 - 88  ELSE TXN_MTH - 1  END "MTH_BEFORE",
                LAG(TXN_MTH) OVER(Partition By CONTACT_KEY Order By CONTACT_KEY, TXN_MTH) "MTH_PREV_TXN",
                TXN_MTH - (LAG(TXN_MTH) OVER(Partition By CONTACT_KEY Order By CONTACT_KEY, TXN_MTH)) "MTHS_SINCE_PREV_TXN",
                Min(TXN_MTH) OVER(Partition By CONTACT_KEY Order By CONTACT_KEY) "FIRST_MTH",
                Max(TXN_MTH) OVER(Partition By CONTACT_KEY Order By CONTACT_KEY) "LAST_MTH",
                Max(TXN_MTH) OVER(Partition By CONTACT_KEY Order By CONTACT_KEY) - Min(TXN_MTH) OVER(Partition By CONTACT_KEY Order By CONTACT_KEY) + 1 "TOTAL_MTHS"
            From
                tbl
        )
/*  R e s u l t :
BU_CODE     BU_KEY CONTACT_KEY    TXN_MTH FRAGRANCE_FLAG COSMETICS_FLAG PERSONALCARE_FLAG MTH_BEFORE MTH_PREV_TXN MTHS_SINCE_PREV_TXN  FIRST_MTH   LAST_MTH TOTAL_MTHS
------- ---------- ----------- ---------- -------------- -------------- ----------------- ---------- ------------ ------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
TPS             16        1196     202108              1              0                 0     202107                                      202108     202112          5 
TPS             16        1196     202111              1              0                 0     202110       202108                   3     202108     202112          5 
TPS             16        1196     202112              1              0                 0     202111       202111                   1     202108     202112          5 
TPS             16        1259     202109              1              0                 0     202108                                      202109     202109          1 
TPS             16        1443     202106              1              0                 0     202105                                      202106     202109          4 
TPS             16        1443     202109              1              0                 0     202108       202106                   3     202106     202109          4 
TPS             16        1478     202107              0              0                 0     202106                                      202107     202107          1 
TPS             16        1570     202108              1              0                 0     202107                                      202108     202108          1 
TPS             16        1637     202105              1              0                 0     202104                                      202105     202109          5 
TPS             16        1637     202106              1              0                 0     202105       202105                   1     202105     202109          5 
TPS             16        1637     202107              1              0                 0     202106       202106                   1     202105     202109          5 
TPS             16        1637     202109              1              0                 0     202108       202107                   2     202105     202109          5 
TPS             16        1675     202106              1              0                 0     202105                                      202106     202106          1
*/
```

Now we have more than everything we need to get you your expected result. Using the CTE's resulting dataset like below hopefuly will answer your question.

```sql
Select 
    BU_CODE, BU_KEY, CONTACT_KEY, 
    TXN_MTH, 
    FRAGRANCE_FLAG, COSMETICS_FLAG, PERSONALCARE_FLAG,
    MTH_PREV_TXN,
    CASE  
        WHEN MTH_PREV_TXN Is Null THEN 'NEW'
        WHEN Nvl(MTHS_SINCE_PREV_TXN, 0) > 12 THEN 'REACTIVATED'
    ELSE 'RETURNING'
    END "CUST_TYPE"
From
    c_months
```

With your sample data (13 rows from the question) it would reasult as:

| BU_CODE | BU_KEY | CONTACT_KEY | TXN_MTH | FRAGRANCE_FLAG | COSMETICS_FLAG | PERSONALCARE_FLAG | MTH_PREV_TXN | CUST_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TPS | 16 | 1196 | 202108 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | NEW |
| TPS | 16 | 1196 | 202111 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 202108 | RETURNING |
| TPS | 16 | 1196 | 202112 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 202111 | RETURNING |
| TPS | 16 | 1259 | 202109 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | NEW |
| TPS | 16 | 1443 | 202106 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | NEW |
| TPS | 16 | 1443 | 202109 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 202106 | RETURNING |
| TPS | 16 | 1478 | 202107 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | NEW |
| TPS | 16 | 1570 | 202108 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | NEW |
| TPS | 16 | 1637 | 202105 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | NEW |
| TPS | 16 | 1637 | 202106 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 202105 | RETURNING |
| TPS | 16 | 1637 | 202107 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 202106 | RETURNING |
| TPS | 16 | 1637 | 202109 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 202107 | RETURNING |
| TPS | 16 | 1675 | 202106 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | NEW |